# Bibtex php preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all, bibtex

I have a text file with a Bibtex export.
The text file has a number of entries following the pattern below.

```
@article{ls_leimeister,
  added-at = {2013-01-18T11:14:11.000+0100},
  author = {Wegener, R. and Leimeister, J. M.},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/27bb26b4b4858439f81aa0ec777944ac5/ls_leimeister},
  journal = {International Journal of Technology Enhanced Learning (to appear)},
  keywords = {Challenges Communities: Factors Learning Success VirtualCommunity and itegpub pub_jml pub_rwe},
  note = {JML_390},
  title = {Virtual Learning Communities: Success Factors and Challenges},
  year = 2013
}
```

I want to use php and considered preg_match_all

The following didnt get me anywhere:

```
preg_match_all('/@^.*}$/', file_get_contents($file_path),$results);
```

I wanted to start simple, but that didnt really work.
I am kinda new to php RegEx.

The perfect final output would be:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['type'] => article
                ['unique_name'] => ls_leimeister
                ['added-at'] => 2013-01-18T11:14:11.000+0100
                ['author'] => Wegener, R. and Leimeister, J. M.
                ['biburl'] => http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/27bb26b4b4858439f81aa0ec777944ac5/ls_leimeister
                ['journal'] => International Journal of Technology Enhanced Learning (to appear)
                ['keywords'] => Challenges Communities: Factors Learning Success VirtualCommunity and itegpub pub_jml pub_rwe
                ['note'] => JML_390
                ['title'] => Virtual Learning Communities: Success Factors and Challenges
                ['year'] => 2013
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [...] => …
            )

    )
```

Comment: @renanbr [renanbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249251/renanbr) recommends: renanbr/bibtex-parser https://github.com/renanbr/bibtex-parser (which I assume is his own invention).

Comment: All BibTex documentation that I have seen will have the year value wrapped in curly brackets.  Is this a typo while posting?

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Here I have fetched only `type` and `unique_name`, by looking at it, you can fetch all others.

```
$str = '@article{ls_leimeister,
  added-at = {2013-01-18T11:14:11.000+0100},
  author = {Wegener, R. and Leimeister, J. M.},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/27bb26b4b4858439f81aa0ec777944ac5/ls_leimeister},
  journal = {International Journal of Technology Enhanced Learning (to appear)},
  keywords = {Challenges Communities: Factors Learning Success VirtualCommunity and itegpub pub_jml pub_rwe},
  note = {JML_390},
  title = {Virtual Learning Communities: Success Factors and Challenges},
  year = 2013
}';

preg_match_all('/@(?P<type>\w+){(?P<unique_name>\w+),(.*)/',$str,$matches);

echo $matches['type'][0];
echo "<br>";
echo $matches['unique_name'][0];
echo "<br>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

Output array format will be little different from yours, but you can change this format to yours.

Comment: Thanks this works, but the other lines are the more diffcult ones.

The number of lines is variable and also some lines have '{ ... },' and others dont.

Comment: Yes, i know it is difficult, but you try to do it.

Comment: preg_match_all('/@(\w+){(.+),\s+(\S+)\s+=\s+{(.*)},(.*)/',$file_content,$results);

This yields the first line as well. How can I tell RegEx to retrieve an indefinite number of lines with the same format?

I would need to read out the matches for the entries and then do another preg_match for the different matches.

Comment: I need to preg_match for all entries first and then do the preg_match I previously posted.
preg_match_all('/@\w+{.+,\s+$([\s\S]+)}$/',$file_content,$results);
preg_match_all('/@\w+{.+,\s+$(.*)}$/',$file_content,$results);

Neither of them work, any help?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Thanks, with your code, I easy to match the keywords such as `title, author` and so on by:`preg_match_all('/(?P<unique_name>\w+)\s=\s\{(.*?)\},/s',$str,$matches);`, note that `/s` means multiline, see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `/^@([^{]+)\{([^,]+),\s*$|^\s*([^\R@=]+) = \{(.*?)}/ms` ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gu4Vx7/1))

This pattern has two alternatives; each containing two capture groups.

- `type` and `unique_name` are captured and stored in elements `[1]` and `[2]`.
- all other key-value pairs are stored in elements `[3]` and `[4]`.

This separated array storage allows reliable processing when constructing the desired output array structure.

Input:

```
$bibtex='@BOOK{ko,
   title = {Wissenschaftlich schreiben leicht gemacht},
   publisher = {Haupt},
   year = {2011},
   author = {Kornmeier, M.},
   number = {3154},
   series = {UTB},
   address = {Bern},
   edition = {4},
   subtitle = {für Bachelor, Master und Dissertation}
}

@BOOK{nial,
   title = {Wissenschaftliche Arbeiten schreiben mit Word 2010},
   publisher = {Addison Wesley},
   year = {2011},
   author = {Nicol, N. and Albrecht, R.},
   address = {München},
   edition = {7}
}

@ARTICLE{shome,
   author = {Scholz, S. and Menzl, S.},
   title = {Alle Wege führen nach Rom},
   journal = {Medizin Produkte Journal},
   year = {2011},
   volume = {18},
   pages = {243-254},
   subtitle = {ein Vergleich der regulatorischen Anforderungen und Medizinprodukte
   in Europa und den USA},
   issue = {4}
}

@INBOOK{shu,
   author = {Schulz, C.},
   title = {Corporate Finance für den Mittelstand},
   booktitle = {Praxishandbuch Firmenkundengeschäft},
   year = {2010},
   editor = {Hilse, J. and Netzel, W and Simmert, D.B.},
   booksubtitle = {Geschäftsfelder Risikomanagement Marketing},
   publisher = {Gabler},
   pages = {97-107},
   location = {Wiesbaden}
}';
```

Method: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c716eb02b3aeba873537d830880483916b09ad36))

```
$pattern='/^@([^{]+)\{([^,]+),\s*$|^\s*([^\R@=]+) = \{(.*?)}/ms';
if(preg_match_all($pattern,$bibtex,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    foreach($out as $line){
        if(isset($line[1])){
            if(!isset($line[3])){  // this is the starting line of a new set
                if(isset($temp)){
                    $result[]=$temp;  // send $temp data to permanent storage
                }
                $temp=['type'=>$line[1],'unique_name'=>$line[2]];  // declare fresh new $temp
            }else{
                $temp[$line[3]]=$line[4];  // continue to store the $temp data
            }
        }
    }
    $result[]=$temp;  // store the final $temp data
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'BOOK',
    'unique_name' => 'ko',
    'title' => 'Wissenschaftlich schreiben leicht gemacht',
    'publisher' => 'Haupt',
    'year' => '2011',
    'author' => 'Kornmeier, M.',
    'number' => '3154',
    'series' => 'UTB',
    'address' => 'Bern',
    'edition' => '4',
    'subtitle' => 'für Bachelor, Master und Dissertation',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'BOOK',
    'unique_name' => 'nial',
    'title' => 'Wissenschaftliche Arbeiten schreiben mit Word 2010',
    'publisher' => 'Addison Wesley',
    'year' => '2011',
    'author' => 'Nicol, N. and Albrecht, R.',
    'address' => 'München',
    'edition' => '7',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'ARTICLE',
    'unique_name' => 'shome',
    'author' => 'Scholz, S. and Menzl, S.',
    'title' => 'Alle Wege führen nach Rom',
    'journal' => 'Medizin Produkte Journal',
    'year' => '2011',
    'volume' => '18',
    'pages' => '243-254',
    'subtitle' => 'ein Vergleich der regulatorischen Anforderungen und Medizinprodukte
   in Europa und den USA',
    'issue' => '4',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'INBOOK',
    'unique_name' => 'shu',
    'author' => 'Schulz, C.',
    'title' => 'Corporate Finance für den Mittelstand',
    'booktitle' => 'Praxishandbuch Firmenkundengeschäft',
    'year' => '2010',
    'editor' => 'Hilse, J. and Netzel, W and Simmert, D.B.',
    'booksubtitle' => 'Geschäftsfelder Risikomanagement Marketing',
    'publisher' => 'Gabler',
    'pages' => '97-107',
    'location' => 'Wiesbaden',
  ),
)
```

Here is [the site](https://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) that I extracted new sample input strings from.